# Are all methods public by default?

Tags: ruby

If I have this in my main program:

```
def hi
  puts 'hi'
end
self.hi
```

it won't work because `hi` is private.

I've learned that all methods in Ruby are public by default, but this doesn't seem to be the case, why?

Comment: Why did you add the self. ?

Answer (score 3):

It is tricky to define a method in the `main` environment. A method is private by default when you define it in `main`. So you either have to use it as private:

```
def hi
  puts 'hi'
end
hi
```

or explicitly make it public:

```
def hi
  puts 'hi'
end
public :hi
self.hi
```

Comment: Great answer. Is there any benefit to doing this though?

Answer (score 1):

Methods are public by default, *except* for "top-level procedures". If you define something which *looks* like a top-level procedure, it will *actually* be defined as a `private` instance method of `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main_method               
  p "This is from main_method"
end                           
public :main_method           

class Klass                   
  def initialize              
    Object.main_method  # Or we can simply say main_method as we do in the second exaple
  end                         
end                           

puts Klass.new
```

It is the way to create Object 'class methods' as shown.  If it were private, then we could not specify the receiver.

When it is private, as it is by default, then we would call it like this:

```
def main_method               
  p "This is from main_method"
end                           

class Klass                   
  def initialize              
    main_method  # With it being private, implicit self only             
  end                         
end                           

puts Klass.new
```

So is there any advantage to either way?  I guess if you make it private, you send some kind of communication to the developer that you have a preference and this should be used as a private method, rather than a public method.

In practice, I don't see an advantage.

Comment: Your sentence "if you make it private ... this should be used as a private ..." is a tautology. It does not have any contentful meaning.

Comment: You are correct about that.  I was thinking about the specific example of `Kernel#puts` and `IO#puts`.  One we should use as a private method and you can't use a receiver explicitly, the other we can specify the receiver and it is mean to be used that way.